# why i receive second request along with first? without any value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I sent an ajax request to retrieve the image name from the gallery and update the ID in the requester page. when i receive the response back i get two response like below,

```
GET http://domain.com/testme/gallery/dynLoad.php?id=159 200 OK 14ms <br>
GET http://domain.com/testme/gallery/dydLoad.php 404 Not Found 4ms
```

1. first response was the intended, it contains the required response. inspected through firebug.
2. I also get the second response immediately after the first with **object not found!** response.

   ```
   $("#show").click(function (){
     $(".wrapper").show('fold', 1000);
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url:"dynLoad.php",
       data: "id="+ <?php echo $id; ?>,
       success: function(){
         $("#gallery").load("dydLoad.php #galleryLoad");
       }
     });
   });
   ```

when i modify the **.ajax()** to **.get()** i still receive the same response but instead of **Not Found** i receive the same response which i got from the previous GET. Again i added those responses below:

GET http://domain.com/testme/gallery/dynLoad.php?id=159 200 OK 13ms 
GET http://domain.com/testme/gallery/dynLoad.php 200 OK 2ms

my code that produces the above response is:

```
$.get("dynLoad.php", {id: "<?php echo $id; ?>"})
        .done(function () {
            $("#gallery").load("dynLoad.php #galleryLoad");
        });
```

i dont understand y that should happen? Anyone has any reason for this occurrence ?

Comment: yes! that was it. your other solution was what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$("#show").click(function (){
  $(".wrapper").show('fold', 1000);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"dynLoad.php",
    data: "id="+ <?php echo $id; ?>,
    success: function(response){
      $("#gallery").load(response);
    }
  });
});
```

**Reason**

your two request are as follow

1. fired with jquery `ajax()`
2. fired after ajax successfully complete in success method with `load()`

> Load method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)

**Other solution**

```
$("#show").click(function (){
    $( "#result" ).load( "dynLoad.php",  {id: "<?php echo $id; ?>"} );
});
```

Comment: .load() - Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
    $(document).on('click',"#show",function (){ //
        $(".wrapper").show('fold', 1000);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"dynLoad.php",
            data: "id="+ <?php echo $id; ?>,
            success: function(){
                $("#gallery").load("dydLoad.php #galleryLoad");
            }
        });
    });
```